# Getting errors with Google Maps API, using recompose and react-google-maps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, react-google-maps

I'm using Google Maps API to show places on a map. However, every time I drag the location on my map, I get the following errors:

[image: errors on console]

Here is my Google map, using Google Maps API, [recompose](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose) and [react-google-maps](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps). It works, but is giving errors.

```
/*global google*/
import React from "react"
import { compose, withProps, withHandlers, withState } from "recompose"
import { withScriptjs, withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Marker } from "react-google-maps"

const MyMapComponent = compose(
    withProps({
        googleMapURL: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places",
        loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
        containerElement: <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />,
        mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    }),
    withScriptjs,
    withGoogleMap,
    withState('places', 'updatePlaces', ''),
    withHandlers(() => {
        const refs = {
            map: undefined,
        }

        return {
            onMapMounted: () => ref => {
                refs.map = ref
            },
            fetchPlaces: ({ updatePlaces }) => {
                let places;
                const bounds = refs.map.getBounds();
                const service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(refs.map.context.__SECRET_MAP_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED);
                const request = {
                    bounds: bounds,
                    type: ['hotel']
                };
                service.nearbySearch(request, (results, status) => {
                    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                        console.log(results);
                        updatePlaces(results);
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }),
)((props) => {
    return (
        <GoogleMap
            onTilesLoaded={props.fetchPlaces}
            ref={props.onMapMounted}
            onBoundsChanged={props.fetchPlaces}
            defaultZoom={8}
            defaultCenter={{ lat: 51.508530, lng: -0.076132 }}
        >
            {props.places && props.places.map((place, i) =>
                <Marker key={i} position={{ lat: place.geometry.location.lat(), lng: place.geometry.location.lng() }} />
            )}
        </GoogleMap>
    )
})

export default class MyFancyComponent extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        return (
            <MyMapComponent />
        )
    }
}
```

I tried looking for a solution at Github issues, Google and here at StackOverflow, but couldn't find a solution yet.

How could I fix the errors, when changing (dragging) the location on the map?

[image: google map with markers]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`withHandlers` expects `fetchPlaces`  function to be a *higher-order function*, so modify:

```
fetchPlaces: ({ updatePlaces }) => {
   //...          
}
```

with

```
fetchPlaces: ({ updatePlaces })  => () => {
   //...
}
```